# How do i pass an eloquent collection to a validation rule?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this rule:

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'category' => [
        'required',
        Rule::notIn(['news', 'article']),
    ],
]);
```

The problem is that news and article are stored in another table. How do i pass the the data from that table into notIn instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use laravel `exists` validation

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name

```php
Validator::make($data, [
    'category' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('tableName')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('column', "active ");
        }),
    ],
]);
``
```

Comment: what if i want to run an extra where condition on it and supply a custom column name?

Comment: for what condition ?

Comment: i have a boolean field for active or inactive on that table

Comment: @on3ss check now